# Removing border lines and keeping plain text in a scanned image form

Tags: java, image, image-processing

I have no of scanned forms and what I want to do is remove lines which separate various fields. The color of the form is black and white.(background white and the text and lines are black) I want to remove lines only and want to keep text for further use.

Comment: *"..for further use."*  What use?

Comment: I want to read all the remaining text using OCR, the problem is the forms are typed manually and hence sometimes the text is up and down, so my OCR reads it sometimes and sometimes it doesnt read it. So what I want to do is remove those lines from text so it will be easy to read..

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Hough transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_Transform) to detect lines.  You can then erase those lines.